# Why i need to install npm for react native app

Tags: reactjs, native

I am learning react native app. My question is "Why do I need to install npm for react native app?", beacuse I think it will install through play store and apple store as a form of bundled apk on user device.
So I am unable to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The development tools depend on Node.js and use modules from NPM.

While React Native gets bundled into an APK, it still uses JavaScript and modules from NPM internally.